# Is it possible to nest a Livewire 3 component independently inside of a form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, livewire-3

I've got a long-running Laravel app with a traditional form in a blade view. Inside of this form I want to start to include a couple Livewire components that can refresh and submit data independent of the form. Is this possible?

For testing purposes I've created this simple component and nested it within the existing `<form>` on the page..

```
<div>
    Time: {{ time() }}
    <button wire:click="$refresh">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

But, clicking the button doesn't refresh the component, and instead submits the form.

Comment: You can try *wire:click.prevent*  (although it shouldn't be necessary) but the refresh will only happen after the long-running process is ended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out there are 2 ways to do this.

1. As @Pippo suggested in the comments:

```
<button wire:click.prevent="$refresh">Refresh</button>
```

2. Having the `type` property set to `button`:

```
<button type="button" wire:click="$refresh">Refresh</button>
```